# WiX how to run exe and (Bootstrapper) installer simultaneously

Tags: windows, wix, custom-action, bootstrapper

My Bootstrapper installer needs to do this, in this order:

1. run an executable that paints a bitmap over the entire screen
2. installs / updates, does its thing
3. reboot

My problem is this:  whenever I run the executable (whether that be through the `<ExePackage>` or through a custom action), the installation stops, and won't continue until either the executable stops (by me manually stopping it) or Hell freezes over.

Note that besides the initial installation, everything has to be done automatically; no human will be present to press any buttons (which is why I have to reboot the machine after the installation is over).

Since the installer freezes on the executable, I can't run another custom action to stop the executable, or, really, do anything.  The problem doesn't lie with my executable, as this happens for any executable (and the behavior happens in toy examples as well).

To illustrate what I mean (and to further demonstrate what I'm talking about), my toy installer's `<Chain>` element looks something like this:

```
<Chain>
    <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.msiA.TargetPath)" /> 
    <ExePackage SourceFile="Show_Bitmap.exe"/>
    <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.msiB.TargetPath)" /> 
    <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.msiC.TargetPath)" /> 
</Chain>
```

When I run this with verbose logging, I get these discrete log files:

1. The Bootstrapper log file (which would show that ***msiA*** was installed and that the executable started).
2. The log file for ***msiA***.

The installation won't actually finish -- it'll get hung up on the exe, which doesn't have a temporal constraint.

However, if I were to change my `<Chain>` element to look like this:

```
<Chain>
    <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.msiA.TargetPath)" /> 
    <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.msiB.TargetPath)" /> 
    <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.msiC.TargetPath)" /> 
    <ExePackage SourceFile="Show_Bitmap.exe"/>
</Chain>
```

and run it with verbose logging, I would get these discrete log files:

1. The Bootstrapper log file (which would show that ***msiA, msiB***, and ***msiC*** were installed, and that the executable started).
2. The log file for ***msiA***.
3. The log file for ***msiB***.
4. The log file for ***msiC***.

And once again I would have to cancel the installation because the exe doesn't have a temporal constraint.

(Note that I get the same behavior if I don't use the  element to run the exe but instead run it using C# through a custom action.)

Ultimately, my question is this:  how can I run an executable so that it runs simultaneously with the rest of the installation?

I realize that this may be a Windows issue as opposed to a Windows Installer issue, but... well, Windows isn't my forte (my forte is building pillow forts).

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Turns out that it was a .Net Process thing....

I should have just put in the code `Process.Start("path\to\Show.Bitmap.exe");`, instead I started the process by going through the entire process of creating the process object (`Process p = new Process(), ..., p.Start()`), etc... I guess when you go through the whole process, it doesn't run asynchronously or something, but when you just call `Process.Start(filename)` it does.

Comment: OK, this is hacking, but how about having another exe/script start up, execute Show_BitMap.exe and exit. I suppose that would let your installation continue. How to remove the bitmap again, I leave up to you.

Comment: Hey, hacking is fine with me!  That's a fantastic idea!

Comment: This leads to an interesting problem:  how to run Show_BitMap.exe?  Since it'll be bundled up into the rest of the installer, it won't have a qualified path.  However, there's a hack-y solution to this:  the initial install will be done by a human with no need for the bitmap to show.  I could install Show_Bitmap.exe on the target machine during the first install so it would have said qualified path...